# FGallery issue on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, fgallery

I am trying to implement FGallery for displaying images in grid view. But i am facing one problem which i explained below:

1. When i try to load images with below method it works,

   NSString *string1 = @"user/name/Library/ApplicationSupport/../Documents/image1.jpg";
   NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: string1,nil];

   The above methods completely works withour error.
2. But When i try to load image with the below method i get only blank image,

   NSString *string1 = (NSString *) [[self.allImagePath valueForKey@"image_Path"] objectAtIndex:0];
   NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: string1, nil];

   The above method load blank images in both grid view and thumbnail view. Please guide me for solution.

Comment: in both case string1 gives same path.but it is not work.

Comment: Have you find the solution in fgallery i am facing same problem.

Comment: yes i find the solution..post your code here..i will let you know the exact solution.

Comment: i have posted the question on this link with code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872200/implemented-fgallery-does-not-display-the-image

Comment: Please refer again FGallery Tutorial code.it will help you most..thanks

Comment: where i can find the FGallery Tutorial Code is any link that you have or any other code ?/

Comment: Follow this link: https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone